# `python -m site --user-site` output is same with or without `sudo`

Tags: python, python-3.6, setup.py

With `sudo`

```
sudo python -m site --user-site
/home1/dilawars/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Without `sudo`

```
python -m site --user-site
/home1/dilawars/.local/lib/python3.6/site-package
```

I really don't get it. I was expecting the output for second case to be different from the first.

I am looking for a solution where following commands `sudo python setup.py install $ARGS` and `python setup.py install ${EXTRA_ARGS}` automatically install the module in ROOT and USER site directories. I was hoping to construct `${EXRA_ARGS}` appropriately using the `site` module depending on if `sudo` was used or not.

### Update

These install commands are generated by `cmake`

```
install(CODE
    "execute_process(
        COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} setup.cmake.py install ${EXTRA_ARGS}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/python
        )"
      )
```

I can not use `pip` since the application is a huge `C++` application with hand-crafted python bindings.

Perhaps I can read `uid` in `setup.cmake.py` and set variables appropriately (if nothing cleaner solution is found).

Comment: For ``root`` you perhaps want ``sudo -H python -m site --user-site``. That way you don't inherit the user environment.

Comment: Cannot duplicate.

Comment: @wim Arch Linux, python3.6 . Same on `Ubuntu 14.04/python2.7`. Results are same for `MacOSX/homebew` with python2.7 .

Comment: Graham's suggestion should work.  Or consider using `pip install --user`.

Comment: You could also try putting `Defaults always_set_home` in sudoers file (`sudo visudo`)